# Enable unit testing of a method my making it protected

Tags: java, styles, tdd

Let me explain the problem scenario. My task is to modify the complicated function testFunc() which looks like below.

```
public String testFunc() {
    String a = func1();
    String b = func2(a);
    String c = func3(b);
    return c;
} 
private String func1(){
    return "hello";
}
private String func2(String p1){
    return "a" + p1;
}
private String func3(String p1){
    return "b" + p1;
}
```

I modify the testFunc method and include my logic. But being a good developer, I wish to write untit tests for the extra logic i have written. 
But i do not have time nor the patience to test the entire method. I wish to test only the logic i have added.

```
 public String testFunc() {
     String a = func1();
     String b = func2(a);
     String c = func3(b);
     String d = func4(c)
     return d;
 }
 protected final String func4(String p1) {
     return "1" + p1;
 }
```

Does it make sense for me to make the method func4 as protected final so that I can unit test the logic thoroughly. Or is it bad coding practise?

Comment: For the record: I would have given a merge of the answers from  assylias and luciano. Turning to reflection for unit test is just asking for trouble. It makes your unit tests slower, and it means that your unit tests break as soon as you start refactoring and change names. If you really want to test this method on its own - either make it package protected *or* move the functionality into its own class and test separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make it package private, which is more restrictive than protected. If you already use Guava in your project you can even annotate the method with [`@VisibleForTesting`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/annotations/VisibleForTesting.html) to make your intention clear:

```
@VisibleForTesting final String func4(String p1) {
  //...
}
```

In the end, a package private method is not exposed to the outside world and is not part of your API, so it doesn't break encapsulation.

Comment: For the record: I think this should be the accepted answer, or maybe the one from luciano.

Answer (score 2):

This IS a bad practice. Private/protected methods should be testable through the public method calling them. By changing the access modifier to package-private, you are essentially exposing implementation details to other classes and thereby decreasing encapsulation.

If this turns out to be hard, you should consider redesigning the public API.

Comment: In an ideal world, yes - but sometimes a class has a public method that does a lot under the hood and testing it as a whole is much more complicated than testing the individual steps that have been delegated to a private method.

Comment: @assylias exactly my point. I am also aware it is a bad practice. Testing the entire public method in my scenario is complicated and i feel it is much cleaner just to test my new logic.

Comment: For the record: I think this should be the accepted answer, or maybe the one from assylias.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the visibility of a method for Unit testing is not a good practice.

If you are using Spring in your project, then you can use [ReflectionTestUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html)`org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils` (reflections simplified) for accessing private methods and propertis.

If you dont want to use Spring then you have to go for java reflections.

Comment: I use spring and i think this is a clean approach. Thank you.:)

Comment: How this possibly could be a clean approach? Relying your tests on private/protected API makes your test fragile and hard to debug, I'm doubt how easy it will be for one to understand one year later why test fails because of small change in private method, especially if you will make it w/ reflection, e.g. simply name refactoring might brake it easily.

Comment: You are right.I think i should reword my comment, it is cleaner than having the method as protected!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd start that two sentence in the question is somewhat contradictionary to me:

1. > But being a good developer, I wish to write unit tests for the extra logic i have written.

And

2. > But i do not have time nor the patience to test the entire method. I
   >   wish to test only the logic i have added.

You either a good developer and doing things right top-down, or doesn't have patience and then nothing really can help you.

To Answer your question, exposing private method which cannot be reused it very bad practice and hence not a good way to approach. While the change you made cannot leave out of the context of the class you did this change for, for example you had:

```
class MyClass {
   public String testFunc() {
      String a = func1();
      String b = func2(a);
      String c = func3(b);
      return c;
   } 
   private String func1(){
      return "hello";
   }
   private String func2(String p1){
      return "a" + p1;
   }
   private String func3(String p1){
      return "b" + p1;
   }
}
```

So there are a few possible ways for you to extend this logic with your new functionality, for example you'd like to [decorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) initial class with a new one and adding new function into it, e.g.:

```
 class MyNewClass extends MyClass{

   private MyClass delegate;

   public MyNewClass(MyClass delegate) {
       this.delegate = delegate;
   }

   public String testFunc() {
      String c = delegate.testFunc();
      return func4(c);
   } 

   private final String func4(String p1) {
      return "1" + p1;
   }
}
```

Now you can write your unit test by [mocking](http://site.mockito.org/) `MyClass` instance and checking only newly added logic only.

Another possible alternative will be extract new functionality into class of its own and write test only for it.